# Interpretation of Strong Law of Large Numbers

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

Here is what [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Strong_law) says about the Strong Law of Large Numbers (SLNN):

> Let $X_1,X_2,X_3,\ldots$ be a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables with $E(X_i)=\mu$, and
> $$\bar{X}_n:=\frac{X_1+\cdots+X_n}{n}.$$
> The Strong Law of Large Numbers (SLNN) states that $\bar{X}_n$ converges almost surely to $\mu$, i.e.,
> $$P(\lim_{n\to\infty}\bar{X}_n=\mu)=1.$$

Consider an experiment of tossing a fair coin. Let $\bar{x}_n$ be the proportion of the number of heads in the first $n$ tosses. SLNN seems to imply the following:

> The probability of $\lim_{n\to\infty}\bar{x}_n=0.5$ is 1.

But how can one calculate the "probability that the numerical sequence $\{\bar{x}_n\}$ converges to 0.5?" (Forgive me if this is a dumb question; I'm new in probability.) I thought along the following line:

- Maybe the sample space $\Omega$ is the set of all sequences like THTHHT$\cdots$. But such $\Omega$ is infinite, so I don't know how to assign a probability to the subset of $\Omega$ consisting of those sequences giving $\lim_{n\to\infty}\bar{x}_n=0.5$. Does one "divide" the cardinality of such subset by the cardinality of $\Omega$ ? (I'm also not too familiar with measure theory.)

Comment: This is an example that shows how useful measure theory is. There's a bit more to it than "dividing" cardinalities.

Comment: "How can one calculate that..."? You use SLLN ;)

Comment: This is done by carefully taking limits over events that involve just the first $n$ random variables. In the coin toss example, all sequences of $n$ coin flips are indeed equally likely with probability $1/2^n$. You can compute the probability that $|\overline{X}_n-1/2|>\epsilon$ to show this goes to zero as $n\rightarrow\infty$ (weak LLN) for any positive $\epsilon$. The strong law is a nontrivial extension that is justified by showing, roughly speaking, that this probability decays fast enough.

Comment: @ashpool, we can compute the complement of the event, e.g., the set $A^c$ containing all those non-convergent points. Then you need to show $P(A^c)=0$. In measure theory, we cannot define probability on a single point e.g., an infinite sequence THTHHT.... But there exists a sigma-algebra that allows us to do the computations. Lastly, it is interesting to note that $A=\{lim\bar{X}_n=0.5\}$ is contained in a tail sigma-algebra. Then the probability has to be one or zero e.g., $P(A)=1$ or $P(A)=0.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to interpret this probability. So think of $w \in \Omega$ as an infinite sequence of coin tosses. So each $\bar X_n(w)$ is average of nth tosses for this specific infinite sequence $w$.

Now, if for example $P(\lim_{n\to\infty}\bar X_n = 0.5)=1$, this means that there exists a set $A \subset \mathcal F$, with $P(A)=1$, where $\mathcal F$ is the sigma-algebra of the probability space. And for every $w\in A$, you have that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \bar X_n(w)= 0.5$.

In other words, for a given $\epsilon>0$, take an infinite sequence $w\in A$. Then, there exists an $N$ such that the sequence of $(\bar X_n(w))$ will fall inside the interval $(0.5 -\epsilon,0.5+ \epsilon)$.

Another way to think of $P(\lim_{n\to\infty}\bar X_n=0.5)$ is the “percentage” of sequences that converge to $0.5$. Note that if you have infinite possible sequences (paths), even if a finite number of them don’t converge to $0.5$, if we assume they are equally likely, then $P(\lim_{n\to\infty}\bar X_n=0.5)$ is still equal to $1$. Now, if one fourth of them converge to $0.5$, then $P(\lim_{n\to\infty}\bar X_n=0.5)=1/4$. And so on.

Comment: I think in all but the first paragraph you really mean $\overline{X}_n$ instead of $X_n$.

Comment: I actually was doing something more general. But I changed to match the user’s question. Thanks for the tip